# If there is a set-cookie response from an xmlhttprequest, will the browser honor it and set the cookie?

Tags: cookies, xmlhttprequest

I'm not trying to send cookie data with the xmlhttprequest, rather I'm trying to use the xmlhttprequest to set cookies for the session without requiring user interaction.

Comment: Can't you use Javascript instead?

Comment: I don't see how that would help, I need to get the cookie from the server, I just don't want to do it as part of a page refresh.

Comment: Did you try it out? Probably be a lot faster than waiting around for someone to answer you. :)

Comment: This is a very interesting question, and I'm surprised there's not a decisive answer to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method):

> If the user agent supports HTTP State Management it should persist, discard and send cookies (as received in the Set-Cookie and Set-Cookie2 response headers, and sent in the Cookie header) as applicable.

As far as I've managed to tell, Firefox 3.6 will store the cookies, but they won't be available to the document of the page which executed the query through `document.cookie`. But they will be sent with subsequent XMXHttpRequests, which is sufficient for my uses.

Comment: but that spec is not yet implemented. It's a candidate recommendation.  The interesting question is, what do the popular browsers of today do with cookies?  and, is the behavior across these browsers consistent?

Comment: So does the fact this was selected as the answer mean that's what happens in all major browsers?

Comment: This is interesting.  In web apps, logins and other activities could occur through asynchronous requests.  Those requests could create cookies with new session ids, and such cookies would have to be sent with all subsequent requests in order for the requests to contain valid app-level session ids.